# Sending Display Driver Maco Commands In C# Via Parallel Port

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parallel-port

I am currently writing a windows form application with C#. The application is for communicating with a parallel port device.

The instructions gives macro command as:
`ESCn<COMMAND>ADDRESS_FIELD<B>DATA_FIELD<D>CHECKSUM`
How would this be submitted via C#?

I've also added an image of the corresponding page from the manual.

[Page from manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEKx0.jpg)
[Additional page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjsb3.jpg)

I have not been able to figure out how to submit the macro command provided via C#.

Comment: A parallel port has 8 data pins, presumably corresponding to the 8 bits in an ascii character. The manual describes how to create a series of ascii characters for a command. But AFAIC there is no builtin parallel port support in c#, so you probably need to use a third party library or native interop.